# weighted sum in terra::project: what are weights?

Tags: sum, raster, projection, weighted, terra

I project a `terra` raster into another `terra` raster, in a different coordinate system, using the `project` function. The `project` documentation states that, for `method="sum"`, it calculates the weighted sum of all non-NA contributing grid cells. I don't quite understand what weights are used here: is it the area of the pixels of the input raster calculated in the projected, template raster? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not very clear and I had the same question for`method = "average"`. `terra` uses [`gdal_warp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) under the hood in these cases, and although the GDAL documentation doesn't give anymore info than the terra documentation, I found [this](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/2363) Github pull request with comments that does help clarify that the weights are the areas of the contributing cells.

The following reprex also confirms that it is area weighted sums:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.55
r <- rast(nrows = 1, ncols = 3)
values(r) <- c(3,5,7)
r2 <- rast(nrows = 1, ncols = 2)

plot(r)
text(r, digits = 1)
lines(as.polygons(r2), col = "red")
```

[image]

```r
r_resample <- resample(r, r2, method = "sum")
plot(r_resample)
text(r_resample, digits = 1)
```

[image]

```r
#this agrees with manual area weighted sum calculation:
#left hand pixel
(3*1 + 5*0.5)
#> [1] 5.5
#right hand pixel
(5*0.5 + 7*1)
#> [1] 9.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>